# python "indexerror: list index out of range" when iterating through files in a directory

Tags: python, indexing, nltk

I have written a program to iterate through files in a directory, get the words that come 1 index before and 2 indexes after a specific word from a list (a sort of highly specific concordance), then compares those words to a dictionary and counts the number of matches. It worked well on a small set of test files, but when applied to a directory of about 800 files, only about half process before I get an "indexerror: list index out of range".

Program

```
import sys
import os
import io
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

files_path = sys.argv[1]
textfile_dictionary = sys.argv[2]

rmsa_words = ["face", "countenance", "manner", "look", "expression", "appearance"]

for filename in os.listdir(files_path):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):

        file = open(os.path.join(files_path, filename), "rt")
        text = file.read()      

        words = word_tokenize(text)

        words = [word.lower() for word in words if word.isalpha()]

        stops = stopwords.words("english")

        tokens = [word for word in words if word not in stops]

        conc_words = []
        i=[]
               
        for word in rmsa_words:        
            i += [x for x, token in enumerate(tokens) if token == word]
        for number in i:
            if number > 0 and number <= (len(tokens) - 2):
                conc_words = conc_words + [tokens[number-1], tokens[number+1], tokens[number+2]]
       
          
        ps = PorterStemmer()

        conc_stems = []
        
        for word in conc_words:
            conc_stems.append(ps.stem(word))
       

        file = io.open(textfile_dictionary, mode="r", encoding="utf8")
        dictionaryread = file.read()
        dictionary = dictionaryread.split()
        

        dictionary_stems = []
        for word in dictionary:
            dictionary_stems.append(ps.stem(word))
        

        rmsa_count = 0

        for element in dictionary_stems:
            for w in conc_stems:
                if w == element:
                    rmsa_count = rmsa_count + 1

        print(filename, len(tokens), rmsa_count)
```

The problem is something to do with the indexing in this section:

```
for word in rmsa_words:        
            i += [x for x, token in enumerate(tokens) if token == word]
        for number in i:
            if number > 0 and number <= (len(tokens) - 2):
                conc_words = conc_words + [tokens[number-1], tokens[number+1], tokens[number+2]]
```

I included the "if number > 0 and number <= (len(tokens) - 2)" to try an stop the loop searching for an index beyond the bounds of the list, but I'm still getting the index error. I have read several index error posts on SO but they are all too different to my code to help.

Any thoughts on why this is working, particularly why it seems to be working for some files and not others, would be much appreciated. I am new to coding.

Comment: You are off by one in your test. Consider the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `number = 2`. Now `number <= len(tokens) - 2` is true, but `tokens[number+2]` is an error because `tokens[4]` is out of range (remember that python is zero indexed...so that last valid index in a list of length 4 is 3.

Comment: Ah, thank you! For the answer and the quick response :) Working perfectly now.